# Retrieve Access Attachments Via VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have some code that will insert attachments to a newly added record in a database:

```
If Attachfile = True Then
            Me.Job_RecordsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Database_Job_RecordsDataSet.Job_Records)
            ' Form1.JobRecordsBindingSource.AddNew()

            Me.DataGridView1.Sort(Me.DataGridView1.Columns(0), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending)

            Dim fd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
            Dim strFileName As String

            fd.Title = "Open File Dialog"
            fd.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
            fd.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*"
            fd.FilterIndex = 2
            fd.RestoreDirectory = True
            fd.Multiselect = True


            If fd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then



                For Each file As String In fd.FileNames

                    strFileName = file

                    Dim dbe As New DBEngine
                    Dim db As Database = dbe.OpenDatabase(Fpath)
                    Dim rstRecord As Recordset = db.OpenRecordset( _
                            "SELECT * FROM [Job Records] WHERE [Job Record]=" & DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value, _
                            RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenDynaset)
                    rstRecord.Edit()
                    Dim rstAttachments As Recordset2 = rstRecord.Fields("Attachments").Value
                    rstAttachments.AddNew()
                    Dim AttachmentData As Field2 = rstAttachments.Fields("FileData")
                    AttachmentData.LoadFromFile(strFileName)
                    rstAttachments.Update()
                    rstAttachments.Close()
                    rstRecord.Update()
                    rstRecord.Close()
                    db.Close()

                Next
            End If
        End If
```

This code works perfectly for what I need it to do. But I need some code to do the reverse and allow me to open the files from the database, in a very similar fashion to how Access will let you open the files if you double click on the attachment field.

I have searched and not really found any examples of this, everyone either links to a microsoft page which has been removed, or gives VBA code for inside access to dump all the attachments, which isn't what I want.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve an attachment you want to use the `.SaveToFile` method of an Access DAO `Field2` object, similar to the `.LoadFromFile` method in your question's example code. See my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25867795/2144390) for details.

Comment: Thanks, however I require multiple files to be viewed, not really saved, and a pop up window to select which file in the database entry you want to open. Its starting to look like I might have to open the access database to do this.