# MS Access embed xslt into vba

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access, xslt

I have two xslt files loaded into my ms access vba. This access database will be passed around so to minimize the xslt files being lost I was wondering if it is possible write the xsl into the vba?

Here is my vba code:

```
    Private Sub btnImport_Click()
    Dim strFile As String, strPath As String
    ' REFERENCE MS XML, v6.0
    Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    strPath = "C:\Users\1122335\Desktop\iavms\IAVM XML dump on 2017-01-20\"
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xml")

    ' LOAD XSL ONLY ONCE
    xslDoc.Load "C:\Users\1122335\Desktop\secondLoad.xsl"

    While strFile <> ""
        ' REINITIALIZE DOM OBJECTS
        Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
        Set newDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

        ' LOAD XML SOURCE
        xmlDoc.Load strPath & strFile

        ' TRANSFORM SOURCE
        xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
        newDoc.Save "C:\Users\1122335\Desktop\temp.xml"

        ' APPEND TO TABLES
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.ImportXML "C:\Users\1122335\Desktop\temp.xml", acAppendData
        strFile = Dir()
    Wend

   ' RELEASE DOM OBJECTS
   Set xmlDoc = Nothing: Set xslDoc = Nothing: Set newDoc = Nothing

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    strPath = "C:\Users\1122335\Desktop\iavms\IAVM XML dump on 2017-01-20\"
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xml")

        ' LOAD XSL ONLY ONCE
    xslDoc.Load "C:\Users\1122335\Desktop\finally.xsl"

    While strFile <> ""
        ' REINITIALIZE DOM OBJECTS
        Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
        Set newDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

        ' LOAD XML SOURCE
        xmlDoc.Load strPath & strFile

        ' TRANSFORM SOURCE
        xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
        newDoc.Save "C:\Users\1122335\Desktop\temp.xml"

        ' APPEND TO TABLES
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.ImportXML "C:\Users\1122335\Desktop\temp.xml", acAppendData
        strFile = Dir()
    Wend

   ' RELEASE DOM OBJECTS
    Set xmlDoc = Nothing: Set xslDoc = Nothing: Set newDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: You want to embed the file binary into VBA as a base-64 string? Why not just embed them in an Access table as `Attachment`s?

Comment: I'm pretty new to access. How would I do that?

Comment: Can't you just store the raw xlst code in a table in the database?

Comment: Create a new table, add a field, and give it a type of `Attachment`, and add an ID field as Primary Key while you're there. Then view the table in Datasheet mode, and double click in the Attachment field, and follow the wizard to attach a file. Then use VBA to open that table and read the attachment.

Comment: That's what @ThunderFrame suggested. What would be the vba code to call that table?

Comment: XLST is just text. All you need is a memo field.

Comment: Brainfart: I read "XLST" as "XLTX", and thought you were embedding an Excel template. If it's just XLST, then as @comintern says, a memo field will work just fine.

Comment: No worries I did it both ways;) so would the code just be `xsldoc [table].[field] where id = 1`?

Comment: When I run the code now I get an error '-2147467259 (800004005)' saying the stylesheet does not contain a document element. The stylesheet may be empty, or it may not be a well-formed xml document. I get this error at `xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc` any suggestions?

Comment: re: retrieving attachment files - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25867795/2144390)

Comment: Did you test it with [an xml validator](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation/)?

Comment: @GordThompson I'm new to VBA and XSL, would you mind explaining how that answer could be used for my problem?

Comment: @Comintern it looks like when vba calls the field it adds a double quote to every double quote. Instead of `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>-->` vba reads `<?xml version=""1.0""?>
<!--<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>-->` throughout the entire xsl file

Comment: @Comintern Nevermind, I don't know what that was about. But both the XML and XSL ran through the validator.

Comment: @1122335 Works in both ADO and DAO for me. `Sub test(): Dim daoRST As DAO.Recordset: Set daoRST = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Table1"): Debug.Print daoRST.Fields("XML").Value:  Dim adoRST As ADODB.Recordset: Set adoRST = CurrentProject.Connection.Execute("Table1"): Debug.Print adoRST.Fields("XML").Value: End Sub`

Comment: @ThunderFrame and @Comintern I'm still getting this error `stylesheet does not contain a document element. The stylesheet may be empty, or it may not be a well-formed xml document` the XML passes validator. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

My answer is probably coming too late but to solve this issue, just change the method "load" to "loadXML":

Change from:
`xmlDoc.Load strPath & strFile`

to:
`xslDoc.loadXML strPath & strFile`